# How to position an input dialog in Java?

Tags: java, dialog, jframe

The following code creates an input dialog. How do I position it? I tried begin.setLocation(X,Y) but this didnt work. I am not sure why.

```
JFrame begin = new JFrame();
Object subjectnumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(begin, "Please enter subject number:");
```

Comment: it didn't work because "begin" is a blank JFrame which you created just to assign it as a parent-frame for your Input-Dialog to make it a modal-dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.setLocation()` did not work because you assigned this to a basic `Object` type.

Try adjusting your definition to

```
JOptionPane subjectnumer = new JOptionPane();
subjectnumber.setLocation(x, y);
String result = subjectnumber.show.....
```

The basic `Object` does not have the method `setLocation`, but `JOptionPane` does.

Comment: When i try to use JOptionPane subjectnumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter subject number"), it asks me to change the type of subjectnumber to String.

Comment: Please see my edits. You should create a `JOptionPane` object, set its position, and then the `showInput...` will return a `String` result of the entered value.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I am not sure why. The third line in my code is String result = subjectnumber.showInputDialog("Please enter");